# How to determine which register a count uses

Tags: tex-core, counters

Suppose there is

```
\newcount\c@mycountera
\newcount\c@mycounterb
\newcount\c@mycounterc
```

Each `\newcount` uses `\alloc@` and that has `\wlog{\string#5=\string#2\the\allocationnumber}`. Thus to determine which register `mycountera` uses I can look into the `.log` file for the (e.g.) `\c@mycountera=\count123`.

But how can I determine the number of the used register inside of LaTeX automatically? (Something like `\registernumber{\c@mycountera}` expanding to `123`.) After `\newcount\c@mycountera` it is `\the\allocationnumber`, but when there is an unknown number of counts created between `\newcount\c@mycountera` and the time when I need the information this does not help. (I cannot use `\xdef\myallocationnumber{\the\allocationnumber}` immediatly after `\newcount\c@mycountera`, because it is defined inside of a package.)

(I suspect that the answer is usable with e.g. \dimen, \box,... too.)

Comment: @Stephen Out of curiosity where are you using this?

Comment: as for example \cl@@ckpt stores all the counters in a list, you could check by inspecting the list as well.

Comment: @Sure, although one could extract those as well. Please see my answer, I think you will end up with issues in any case.

Comment: @Stephen Now that the problem is clearer, perhaps it's better to change the question's title.

Comment: @egreg I asked a separate question for that: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45651/how-do-i-deterime-in-which-order-packages-have-been-loaded . Sorry for the mess I created her.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the fact that `\meaning` will print something like `\countXXX` for a register:

```
\def\registernumber#1{%
  \expandafter\registernumberauxi\meaning#1\halt\stop
}
\def\registernumberauxi#1#2\stop{%
  \ifx\halt#1%
    \expandafter\gobbletwo
  \else
    \expandafter\registernumberauxii
  \fi
    {#1}{#2}%
}
\def\registernumberauxii#1#2{%
  \ifnum`#1<48\else\ifnum`#1>57\else#1\fi\fi
  \registernumberauxi#2\stop
}
\def\gobbletwo#1#2{}
\def\halt{\halt}
\newcount\mycount
\registernumber\mycount
\bye
```

I've used a simple loop to remove the type of register from the front of the number here. There are perhaps better ways to do that, but if proves the principal. The loop uses the fact that `\char48` is 0 and `\char57` is 9, so anything outside of this range is not a number.

Comment: Quite similar to mine. I'd use `\`0` and `\`9` instead of 48 and 57, just not to look at the ASCII table. However, it fails for box registers.

Comment: +1 After gobbling six preceding `\relax` (from `\count`) in the result your answer exactly solves my problem. Thanks! (I'll wait until tomorrow before accepting it, just in the unlikely case there would be another answer.)

Comment: @Joseph a simpler (but devious) test for digits is `\ifnum1<1#1 digit\else non-digit\fi`.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch I was sure there shortcut, but couldn't be bothered to work it out!

Answer (score 7):

Here is one that works also for box registers:

```
\makeatletter
\def\showregister#1{\expandafter\extract@number\meaning#1\showregister}
\def\extract@number#1{%
  \ifx#1\showregister
     \expandafter\@gobbletwo
  \else
     \if\string"#1#1%
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
     \else
       \ifnum`#1<`0 \else \ifnum`#1>`9 \else #1\fi\fi
       \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
     \fi
  \fi
  \extract@rest\extract@number}
\def\extract@rest#1\showregister{#1}

\def\showcounter#1{\expandafter\showregister\csname c@#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\newcount\AAA
\showregister\AAA

\newdimen\AAB
\showregister\AAB

\newlength\AAC
\showregister\AAC

\newsavebox\AAD
\showregister\AAD

\newcount{AAE}
\showcounter{AAE} % or \expandafter\showregister\csname c@AAE\endcsname
```

Box register numbers will be in hexadecimal form, preceded by `"`

The output should be (if starting without any package)

> 79
>   102
>   41
>   "1A
>   80

([Moved additional code to this other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45655/4427))

Here's a LaTeX3 version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\showcounter} { m }
  { \exp_args:Nc \showregister { c@#1 } }
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\showregister} { m }
  {
   \tl_map_function:fN { \cs_meaning:N #1 } \showreg_scan:n
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \tl_map_function:nN { f }
\cs_new:Npn \showreg_scan:n #1
  {
   \bool_if:nT
     {
      (  \int_compare_p:n { `#1 >= `0 } && \int_compare_p:n { `#1 <= `9 } )
      ||
      \int_compare_p:n { `#1 = `" }
      ||
      ( \int_compare_p:n { `#1 >= `A } && \int_compare_p:n { `#1 <= `F } )
     }
     { #1 }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\test#1{\edef\x{\showregister#1}\message{\x\space = \meaning#1}}

\test\fboxsep

\newbox\mybox

\test\mybox
```

The output on the terminal will be

```
36 = \dimen36
"23 = \char"23
```

Comment: @egreg: nitpicking, once more, but variables normally (i.e., in the LaTeX3 naming convention) start with `\l_` or `\g_` or `\c_` depending on whether they are to be modified locally, globally, or not at all (constants).

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch You're right, of course

Answer (score 4):

This is too long for a comment. As per the OP the counter number is to be used
for checking the order of packages loaded. This is highly unlikely that it can be a full
proof technique.

`LaTeX2e`, stores all the counters allocated in an `\@elt` list called  `\cl@@ckpt`.

The following MWE will display all counters allocated and the name of the 
counter i.e., the part after `c@`. As you will observe by running the example, hyperTexies like Heiko will fiddle the system. Mostly though, it will predict order of loading:

```
% See all the counters in LaTeX2e
% and their allocation numbers
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{ZZZ}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\Z{%
   \def\@elt##1{%
       \expandafter\meaning
       \csname c@##1\endcsname
       \space = ##1,\par
    }%
   \cl@@ckpt%
}
All counter in article class plus one!
Expand list.

\Z

\section{Test}
\ifcsname c@section@level\endcsname 
   hyperef package has been loaded
    \else 
   not loaded
\fi
%\expandafter\let\csname c@section@level\endcsname\undefined 
\the\count118

\the\c@section@level

\end{document}
```

A better way to check for file order is to check the `@filelist`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{ctr}
\makeatletter
\let\afilelist\@filelist
\begin{document}
% Just to see files
\@for\next:=\afilelist\do{%
 \next, \par
}
% Command factory
\stepcounter{ctr}
\@for\next:=\afilelist\do{%
      \expandafter\edef\csname @\next\endcsname{\thectr}
     \stepcounter{ctr}
}

% Define macro to check order
\def\checkpkgorder#1#2{%
   \edef\X{\csname @#1\endcsname}
    \edef\Y{\csname @#2\endcsname}
    \expandafter\ifnum\X\expandafter<\Y
      Yes loaded earlier \X, \Y
     \else
      No loaded later \X, \Y
   \fi
}

\checkpkgorder{book.cls}{ifxetex.sty}
\end{document}
```