# How do I determine in which order packages have been loaded?

Tags: packages

The `\listfiles` command will give the list of all loaded files (and therefore also packages) at the end of the `.log` file, but how do I determine from inside LaTeX, whether package A was loaded before package B or vice versa?

Comment: Please note: While the question is about *packages*, the answers are also usable for other files!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can access the list as a comma separated list of filenames in `\@filelist`

If you need this check after `\begin{document}` use `\listfiles` so LaTeX saves that information.

`\listfiles` does

```
  \@for\@currname:=\@filelist\do{%
      .....
```

to iterate over this list.

So for example you could define

```
\makeatletter

\def\test#1#2{%
\def\hmma{#1.sty}%
\let\hmmb\@empty
\@for\@currname:=\@filelist\do{%
   \ifx\@currname\hmma
     \def\hmmb{#2.sty}%
   \fi
   \ifx\@currname\hmmb
       \typeout{#1 loaded before #2}%
   \fi}}
```

then using this as:

```
\test{marginnote}{geometry}
```

will type out

```
marginnote loaded before geometry
```

if that is in fact the case.

As noted in the comments you might want to use different comand names in production code, also if the two `.sty` are removed from the test you can test other files such as class and def files that are listed by LaTeX, but would need to explicitly use the extension, so `\test{marginnote.sty}{geometry.sty}`

Comment: `\@filelist` was the information I was missing! Thanks! 

`\@currname` collides with the `hyperref` package: 

! Undefined control sequence. 
 
\@currname ->\@nil 

Replacing `\@currname` by `\@dc` (or something longer, which is probably better to make sure it is not used elsewhere) works (got that `\hmma`/`\hmmb` ;-)). `\newcommand{\test}[2]` instead of  `\def\test#1#2` might be considered, too.

Comment: While my question was about packages, you might want to add a note that your answer also works for any files, if `.sty` is removed from the code and `\test{marginnote.sty}{geometry.sty}` is used. For other files e.g. `\test{subdocumentabcd.tex}{subdocumentzyxw.tex}` or checking for `.cfg` or included `.pdf` or whatsoever is then possible. Your solution is robust but not complicated. A really nice answer. (Your new badge already says so.) +1 (yesterday) and now also accepted.

Comment: This answer is responsible for [this bug](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261448/), according to comments in the package file ;).

Comment: @cfr I'm sure I've never been responsible for a package bug, the comment must be in error!

Answer (score 9):

Here's a way: the code from `\usepackage{xparse}` to `\ExplSyntaxOff` should go before checking any package, of course. The definition of the `\test` command is just for showing that the code works, though, and can be removed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_pkgfirst_list_seq
\bool_new:N \l_pkgfirst_tmpa_bool
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { Nnx }
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifpackagefirst}{mmmm}
  {
   \bool_set_false:N \l_pkgfirst_tmpa_bool
   \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_pkgfirst_list_seq {,} { \use:c { @filelist} }
   \seq_if_in:NnT \l_pkgfirst_list_seq {#1} { \bool_set_true:N \l_pkgfirst_tmpa_bool }
   \seq_if_in:NnT \l_pkgfirst_list_seq {#2} { \bool_set_true:N \l_pkgfirst_tmpa_bool }
   \bool_if:NTF \l_pkgfirst_tmpa_bool
     { \pkgfirst_compare:nnnn {#1}{#2}{#3}{#4} }
     { \msg_term:x {OOPS,~packages~not~both~loaded} }
  }
\cs_new:Npn \pkgfirst_compare:nnnn #1 #2 #3 #4
  {
   \bool_set_false:N \l_pkgfirst_tmpa_bool
   \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_pkgfirst_list_seq
     {
      \str_if_eq:nnT { #1 } { ##1 }
        { \prg_map_break:n { \bool_set_true:N \l_pkgfirst_tmpa_bool } }
      \str_if_eq:nnT { #2 } { ##1 }
        { \prg_map_break:n { \bool_set_false:N \l_pkgfirst_tmpa_bool } }
     }
   \bool_if:NTF \l_pkgfirst_tmpa_bool {#3} {#4}
  }


\NewDocumentCommand\test{m m}
  {\ifpackagefirst{#1}{#2}{\msg_term:x {#1~before~#2}}{\msg_term:x {#1~after~#2}}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\test{graphicx.sty}{imakeidx.sty}

\test{imakeidx.sty}{kantlipsum.sty}

\test{kantlipsum.sty}{graphicx.sty}

\test{pippo.sty}{pluto.sty}

\stop
```

This is the output:

```
*************************************************
* graphicx.sty before imakeidx.sty
*************************************************
*************************************************
* imakeidx.sty before kantlipsum.sty
*************************************************
*************************************************
* kantlipsum.sty after graphicx.sty
*************************************************
*************************************************
* OOPS, packages not both loaded
*************************************************
```

Usage:

```
\ifpackagefirst{package1.sty}{package2.sty}
  {code to be executed if 1 has been loaded before 2}
  {code to be executed if 2 has been loaded before 1}
```

If the packages are not *both* loaded, no code will be executed.

Comment: It is good to have a completely different kind of solution for the problem.

Answer (score 9):

A way to check for file order is to check the order of the files loaded in the `@filelist`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcounter{ctr}
\makeatletter
\let\afilelist\@filelist
\begin{document}
% Just to see files
\@for\next:=\afilelist\do{%
 \next, \par
}
% Command factory
\stepcounter{ctr}
\@for\next:=\afilelist\do{%
      \expandafter\edef\csname @\next\endcsname{\thectr}
     \stepcounter{ctr}
}

% Define macro to check order
\def\checkpkgorder#1#2{%
   \edef\X{\csname @#1\endcsname}
    \edef\Y{\csname @#2\endcsname}
    \expandafter\ifnum\X\expandafter<\Y
      Yes loaded earlier \X, \Y
     \else
      No loaded later \X, \Y
   \fi
}

\checkpkgorder{book.cls}{ifxetex.sty}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For checking after `\begin{document}` and to cover `a before b` as well as `b before a` in one step your code is really useful, but because I need neither of those I accepted the answer of David Carlisle.

Comment: @Stephen Not to worry, David's answer was very elegant. It deserved to be accepted. Upvoted it myself also.