# How can I continue using both pageslts and tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, packages, incompatibility, pageslts

A recent update to my TeX Live installation appears to have given rise to an incompatibility between two packages: `pageslts` and `tikz`. The following document does not compile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
  abc
\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@currname ->\@nil

l.10 \begin{document}
```

It is possible to workaround this problem by loading `tikz` before loading `pageslts`. However, this would require me to load `tikz` in custom class and package files since I use `pageslts` there. If possible, I'd like to avoid doing this as most of my documents do not require TikZ and I'd rather not load it when not needed.

One approach would obviously be to create class/package options allowing me to specify when TikZ is required. However, I'm wondering if that is the best approach or if there's a better solution.

Right now, `pageslts` is causing me a great deal of grief - this is the second package I've discovered must now be loaded first. (At least the first case gave me a semi-helpful error message.)

So if there is a good alternative to `pageslts`, I'd be interested in learning about it since the package seems to have suddenly become rather finicky and no longer gets along nicely with anything else!

Comment: I'd call this a bug. By the way, `pageslts` calls `\listfiles`, which is *very* annoying.

Comment: @egreg Oh, is it this that's responsible? I was going to track that down but the errors have been taking priority. It is, indeed, very annoying. Is it a bug even though changing the loading order avoids the error? `mathtools` also now must be loaded before `pageslts`. The documentation says that the package no longer requires e-TeX but I'm not clear why that is meant to be such an advantage!

Comment: The problem with `\listfiles` shouldn't be connected with the bug.

Comment: @egreg I didn't really expect it to be ;). But is it a bug if it just requires a different load order? That's not uncommon, after all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bug is in lines 115–119 of `pageslts.sty`, where `\@currname` is used in a `\@for` cycle, leaving a definition of `\@currname`, which is unexpected.

If I change the three occurrences of `\@currname` with `\next`, the problem disappears.

Of course, also the appearance of `\listfiles` on line 111 is wrong, but this is unrelated, only annoying.

---

The macro `\@currname` is used during package loading, for making a stack in order to correctly reset the status of `@` as a letter or as an “other character”. It is also reused in `\listfiles` as the placeholder for a `\@for` cycle, but in that case it's not a problem, because `\listfiles` is processed only at the end of a job. The similar usage by `pageslts` instead is wrong, because it clearly interferes with package loading. If you add `\errorcontextlines=100` at the beginning of the test file you get

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\@currname ->\@nil 

\@pushfilename ...ef \@currnamestack {{\@currname 
                                                  }{\@currext }{\the \catcod...

\@onefilewithoptions #1[#2][#3]#4->\@pushfilename 
                                                  \xdef \@currname {#1}\glob...

\reserved@a ...ds[{}][{2007/11/11}]\@pkgextension 
                                                  \relax 
<argument> ...uirePackage {pdftexcmds}[2007/11/11]
                                                  \expandafter \ifx \csname ...

\@secondoftwo #1#2->#2

\@begindocumenthook ...base}[2009/07/12]\fi \fi }}
                                                   \pgfsys@atbegindocument \...

\document ...ent \@firstofone \@begindocumenthook 
                                                  \ifdim \topskip <1sp\globa...
l.5 \begin{document}
```

showing that the problem is when processing `\RequirePackage{pdftexcmds}`.

Comment: Thanks! I've reported this to the package author, quoting the first two paragraphs of your answer. I agree `\listfiles` is annoying but I suppose it isn't technically wrong.

Comment: I don't entirely understand why using `\@currname` is a problem, though.

Comment: Be nice if the updated version of `atveryend` was available, too, but it is not yet on CTAN despite the note dating it to 1st August :(.

Answer (score 1):

This was indeed a bug. Thank you for reporting it! Version 1.2e as of 2015/08/17 (should become available soon at [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pageslts), has been submitted 2015-08-17 21:24 CEST) uses `\next`, as suggested in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261448/6865), and also does no longer include the `\listfiles`. (The example file still includes `\listfiles`, because it is to be expected that possible problems with the example might be connected to the use of either older or newer versions of other packages.) The requested `atveryend` has been dated *later* 2015/08/01, because before that date there was no new version, and the next version (whether 2015/08/18 or 2016/01/01) will surely have this fixed. - I marked this answer "community wiki", `upvotes` and `accepted answer` should (in my humble opinion) go to [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261448/6865)!

Comment: Thank you very much! And thank you also for the email telling me this. You might consider using something a bit more package-specific than `\next`, though.  My hacked version is currently using `\@pageslts@currname` just to be on the safe side ;).